# jQuery animate() function cannot move a group of nested elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I run into this problem when creating a thumbnail slider. I have 2 elements - `<ul>` with class B is nested inside `<div>` A.

I would like to be able to move `<ul`> B to the right and left using some jQuery functions like `animate()`. The problem is It doesn’t seem to work at all. Element `<ul>` B cant be simply moved.

Maybe I did something wrong or maybe I just dont understand how it all works. Please help me.

Here is my CODEPEN link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqGVaN

```
<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<button>Animate</button>

<script>
$(button).click(function(){
  $(".b").animate({letf: "130px"});  
  //DIV class="b" CAN NOT BE MOVED through DIV class="a"
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border: 3px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.b > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 45px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Typo in `.animate({letf: "130px"})`. And unless `button` is a variable, you're missing quotes around it in `$(button)`. And finally, once you fix those typos, the root issue is that you never set a position on the `.b` element. Add `position:relative` to it and it'll  move.

Comment: Another typo: script tags spelled wrong <script><\script> not skript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/vwvn7uvn/1/

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $(".b").animate({left: "130px"});  
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border: 3px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.b > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 45px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<button>Animate</button>
```

Two changes I made to the code.

**JS**

Spelling mistake **letf** changed to **left**

**CSS** (added)

.b{
   position: relative;
}

Comment: Please explain your solution. "Here you go" is insufficient

Comment: I have applied your styles to my final project here:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayZbRN. 

Whilst `.animate({left: "530px"});` works fine, `.animate({right: "530px"});` does NOT. I checked for typos, none found.

Comment: Instead of right 530px, try using .animate({left: "0px"}); ... Please create a jsfiddle, I'm unable to access codePen as it's reloading continuously....

Comment: @Shiladitya I tried but with no success. Here is a FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/u1ssajye/1/

Comment: @BB-8 .. Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/u1ssajye/2/ .  or   https://jsfiddle.net/u1ssajye/3/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your JQuery is invalid. As @j08691 poited out, `.animate({letf: "130px"})` has a typo.

Not only that, but the button JQuery selector is also invalid. Try adding an ID, as the speed JQuery queries the DOM is alot faster.

You should also leverage native CSS transitions, this is alot faster also. A snippet below:

```js
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $(".b").toggleClass('animated');  
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border: 3px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  transition: left .2s ease; 
}

.b.animated {
  left: -130px;
}

.b > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 45px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <ul class="b">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="myButton">Animate</button>
```